# Azure Failed to load deployment logs:?

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

While working on Azure Web App I was deploying a new web app via Vs code when I got the errors...

Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, close
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Kudu Sync failed
Deployment Failed

In an attempt to fix it, on the web app service overview tab on the top (see image) [image: web app overview tab]

I hit restart, tried again, but nothing changed (I thought this was do to a tmp file issue), then I pressed get publish profile, no cahnage either. Eventually however I checked my logs in deployment center I found this(see image) [image: Deployment Log]

Now I cannot deploy anything again since vs code will always tell me there is a deployment in progress, and I can also not cancel any deployment processes. Additionally I have no idea what is going on with that deployment. It appears my app service is stuck.

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?